# Doubts about identifiers in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cannot figure out why i get this behavior with the execution this piece of code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Countries = require(./countries.js),
Countries = mongoose.model('Countries');

Countries.find({name: 'Germany'}, function(err, obj){
   console.log(obj._id);
   console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(obj._id));
   console.log(obj);
});
```

Here the results:

```
undefined
539c96e09d494a0000aff5cb
{ _id: 539c65a6d8d18d0000f5cf64,
name: 'Germany',
__v: 0 }
```

Only the id printed with the whole object is correct (verified looking directly at the db using Robomongo).

Since i need to take that id to save it as reference to another collection, do you have any suggestion and/or why such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obj is a collection so your results are probably not what you expect.

```
Countries.find({name: 'Germany'}, function(err, countries){
  countries.forEach(function(obj) {
   console.log(obj._id);
   console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(obj._id));
   console.log(obj);
   });
});
```